# How do I install Chrome on a server?

Tags: command-line, server, google-chrome

I'm a complete newbie to Ubuntu Server and am looking for a web browser which I am learning to use as it is a requirement of the course I'm doing.
It's been many a year since I've spent any time poking around a CLI and am constantly going back and forward between various websites for hints on coding.
I'm running this in VMWare and it would make life a bit easier if I could find a decent web browser to use.
I won't use Firefox as I find it too unstable and don't use it on my windows box... I've tried Links2 and a couple of other light weight broswers but I'm not keen.

Can any one give an idiots guide to what I need to do to set up Chrome or something similar to run on Ubuntu server.

Comment: So you got a GUI ?

Comment: as a server user to isntall/remove pkgs you'd better have aptitude knowledge http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=37736

Comment: How do you want to access the browser? By the terminal? By a screen attached to the server? By other means?

Comment: It's a virtual server running in VMware so I just want some way of running some from of chrome from the CLI. I have no sort of GUI installed...

Comment: @Gibboncore So you want access from chrome to a website executed in the VMware server. Do you want to install a web browser inside the server instead than accessing from the host server? Accessing from the host server would be faster and it would mess less with the virtual machine. But I don't know if it is a requirement of that course to do it the other way around.

Comment: no it isn't a requirement of the course its just after years of using windows I'm so used to pressing ctrl alt del that I do it on auto pilot and in VMWare that causes the server to reboot which is not allways convenient ;^) I'll just have to get used to ctrl del to move out of the VM!!!

Comment: it is a requirement do do it all without a GUI and I hadn't realised that it was either a full GUI or nothing: I did say I was a newbie ;^)

Answer (score 15):

> **The installation Procedure for Google Chrome Browser 64-bit version 73.0.3683.86.**

**Step-1:** First, add (if not added already) the Google Chrome repository on your system using the following command. While using PPA to our system we also receive the latest updates whenever you check for system updates.

```
$ wget -q -O - https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | sudo apt-key add -
```

Now add the PPA url to the `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list` file as per Ubuntu system architecture.

```
$ sudo sh -c 'echo "deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list'
```

**Step-2:** Install or Upgrade Google Chrome

After adding Google Chrome repository in our system use following commands to install the latest Google Chrome stable release. If you already have installed an older version, It will upgrade currently installed version with recent stable version.

```
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install google-chrome-stable
```

**Step-3:** Verify version

`$ google-chrome --version`

[image]
`Figure-1: Google Chrome latest version 73.0.3683.86`

you will see the output will be Google Chrome 73.0.3683.86.

**Step-4:** Launch Google Chrome

After completing step-3 the Google Chrome has been installed successfully on your system. Finally issue command to see Chrome browser:

`$ google-chrome-stable &`

**Note:** You can also access Chrome browser through `Gnome dash` and double-click chrome browser `shortcut`.

Answer (score 5):

Open your terminal and type this

```
wget https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_i386.deb
sudo dpkg -i google-chrome-stable_current_i386.deb
```

That above chrome is good for 32-bit systems. Here's the URL for 64-bit systems:

```
https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
```

And [here's the download page](https://www.google.com/intl/en/chrome/browser/) in case these URLs change in the future.

Comment: What is the difference between chromium-broswer in rthe update Centre and Chrome for Unix from the Google website?

Comment: @Gibboncore Chromium-browser is the open source project which chrome is based in. Essentially chromium is the same as chrome apart from not having flash built-in, not having support for google cloud print and a colorless icon (and some other things like that ;))
IMHO if you do not require flash I would totally choose chromium. Which is probably your case

Comment: ERROR 404: Not Found.

Answer (score 5):

try this command in terminal to download the .deb package

```
wget https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
```

In the next step install the local .deb by executing the following command:

```
sudo dpkg -i google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
```

Answer (score 3):

Well you need a Environment here .

In the Ubuntu the very Light DE's are Lubuntu and Xubuntu.

you can get them by doing like

```
sudo apt-get install xubuntu
sudo apt-get install lubuntu
```

Run this command:

```
sudo apt-get install chromium-browser
```

There a post we have here with low memory usage browsers, may be that gonna help you in a better way.[CLICK HERE](https://askubuntu.com/questions/196339/what-are-the-available-browsers-for-128-mb-of-ram-pc)

Comment: if the OP is running a default ubuntu server, there probably will be no graphical environment...

Comment: @Nanne to execute that command we just need a Terminal.

Comment: yes that's right no graphical environment... can I install some sort of low footprint version?

Comment: @snow: obviously. But the problem is to run chrome you need to install a complete X-system, and I don't think the CLI line for `apt-get`ting chromium is the way to help a beginner install a window-environment. This will give all sorts of dependencys. Just giving this line without going in to that isn't helping I believe. @gibboncore: if you want chrome, you need a graphical enviroment. Maybe you'd be better off just installing a desktop version instead of ubuntu server?

Comment: @Nanne I agree with you. I have added remaining part of the answer.

Comment: @snow I don't want to install a full on graphical environment or the desktop version as I need to be working with with server on a CLI. From my limited experience of trying to use a GUI on a server it's not something I'm planning on trying again. I just want a half decent easy to use browser which will allow me to keep the server environment pretty much as it is.

Comment: Sorry  the above should also have been addressed to @Nanne as well. To add a little mor to the above... Is it possible install any of these lightweight broswers without having to suffer a GUI. If not then I'll save everyone a lot of bother and just do without!!!

Comment: you need a graphical environment (lightweight or no, you need one) to run graphical programs. If you don't want that, install a text-browser (lynx/links/links2).

Comment: google-chrome: not found

Comment: chrome: command not found

Answer (score 0):

I think that the easiest way would to run your VMWare OS and have chrome open in the background- other than having Chrome in a Command Line Interface environment. Then when you have them both open, `Ctrl` + `Alt` then use `Alt` + `Tab`. to swap between chrome. Ever tried using 2 screens or using a phone or tablet as another way of accessing help?
(sorry I can't figure out or find how to make my key presses look like keys)

Comment: With respect, what are you trying to say here?

Answer (score 0):

###### Install npm and puppeteer

```
sudo apt install npm
sudo npm install -g puppeteer # sudo is optional to install puppeteer globally
```

###### Install Chrome using `npx`

```
npx @puppeteer/browsers install chrome@stable
```

###### Download a specific Chrome version.

```
npx @puppeteer/browsers install chrome@116.0.5793.0
```

###### It will download the Chrome binary. Move the downloaded folder to a directory where you want to install Chrome

```
sudo mv chrome /usr/local/
```

###### Update symbolic link to point to the chrome binary, Here is an example.

```
sudo ln -s /usr/local/chrome/linux-121.0.6167.85/chrome-linux64/chrome /usr/bin/chrome
```

###### Verify installation

```
chrome --version
```

Comment: How do i put it in puppeteer im suffering, i need to add a chrome.exe to it but THERE ISNT ANY